# How to run a Java program under cron and import the jars

Tags: java, cron, terminal, noclassdeffounderror

My source file is `.../MyDir/proj/myProj.java`. The jar files are under `.../MyDir/proj/library`. The jar files are from [HTMLUnit 2.10](http://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlunit/files/).

This is the source for my cron file:

```
0 0 * * * java -classpath .../MyDir/proj/ myProj
```

But it gave me the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient
```

How do I modify the cron file to import the jar files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
0 0 * * * java -classpath .../MyDir/proj/:.../MyDir/proj/library/jar1.jar:.../MyDir/proj/library/jar2.jar myProj
```

or if you are using a recent JVM you can use a wildcard to match all of the JAR files.

```
0 0 * * * java -classpath .../MyDir/proj/:.../MyDir/proj/library/\* myProj
```

(The backslash is probably unnecessary because 'globbing' is unlikely to match anything in that context ...)

---

Better still, put the command (and any others that need to be run to prepare for the launch) into a shell script, and run the script from your crontab entry instead.

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple to **implement the CRON Job in java**

**Required Library:**
*quartz-2.0.0.jar*

**Scheduler Initiator:**

```
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.newJob;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.newTrigger;

import java.text.ParseException;

import org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

public class SchedulerListener{

    static Scheduler scheduler = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Setup the Job class and the Job group
        JobDetail job = newJob(FileUploadToAzure.class).withIdentity(
                        "CronQuartzJob", "Group").build();

        // Create a Trigger that fires every hour.
        Trigger trigger;
        try {
            trigger = newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("TriggerName", "Group")
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 * * * ?"))
            .build();

            // Setup the Job and Trigger with Scheduler & schedule jobs
            scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            scheduler.start();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

        } catch (ParseException | SchedulerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

**Scheduler Class:**

```
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class SchedulerJob implements Job {
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println("Print at specific time");
}
}
```

**CronTrigger**

```
Expression  Meaning :
---------------------------
0 0 12 * * ?    Fire at 12pm (noon) every day
0 15 10 ? * *   Fire at 10:15am every day
0 15 10 * * ?   Fire at 10:15am every day
0 15 10 * * ? * Fire at 10:15am every day
0 15 10 * * ? 2005  Fire at 10:15am every day during the year 2005
0 * 14 * * ?    Fire every minute starting at 2pm and ending at 2:59pm, every day
0 0/5 14 * * ?  Fire every 5 minutes starting at 2pm and ending at 2:55pm, every day
```

**[More details about CRON Trigger, then please refer below link](http://www.askmani.net/question/crontrigger/)**

http://www.askmani.net/question/crontrigger/

Comment: last two links are dead

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot Java users, you can use **@scheduled** annotation. For more details and a great example, visit [this](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-task-scheduling-with-scheduled-annotation)