# using crontab to call a webmethod?

Tags: java, soap, cron

I am new to crontab and I wanted to know how I could call a web method every week using crontab.

I have a webmethod in java and I created a wsdl for these webmethods and now I am able to test this web method through the SOAP UI. What I actually thought was to create a .xml for this webmethod and then call it using crontab. But I am not sure whether it would work. Please elaborate and let me know how this functionality can be achieved.

Comment: In the crontab, you specify a schedule and shell command to run.

Comment: yeah I understand that we need to specify a schedule and then give a script which it will run.I wanted to know how I could write the script to call the web method.

Comment: The premise of your question is a little misguided, but still answerable.  `cron` can invoke executables and you'll need an executable to invoke your web method.

Comment: Learn bash/shell scripting. The script would execute, possibly, some java application that send a request to the web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cron can run any executable, or perhaps more correctly, executables that don't require a connection to a display.

To do what you want, create a standalone program that calls whatever functions you want. Make sure you can run this from the command line, and that the program doesn't open any windows.

You should then be able to configure your crontab to run this program whenever you want.

You might be interested in the answers to this question: [How to run a Java program under cron and import the jars](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11840059/7432)

Comment: So I have a Java program and I need to execute this through a shell script.Could you please help. Also can a crontab run the java program directly without any script?

Comment: Yes, cron can run a java program directly. It can run any executable, and "java" is an executable. Though, you might have more luck with a shell script since you can modify the classpath and do other sorts of initializations more easily. I've updated my answer to link to a question that shows how to call java directly.

Answer (score 0):

I see two parts in your question:

1. how to call a SOAP web service from the command line (as that will make cron integration possible:  answered [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222607/how-to-do-a-soap-wsdl-web-services-call-from-the-command-line) using cURL
2. how to schedule a weekly job with cron: for example, schedule the job at 0:40 on monday

   40 0 * * 1 /path/to/the/script/that/implements/part.1

As an alternatively trick if you are on a system where you cannot directly add something to crontab, only scripts to say /etc/cron.daily, you can use a cron.daily script that will only actually do something 1 day per week like this (this example also for execution on monday only):

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ `date +%u` -eq 1 ] ; then
   # do whatever you need to do
fi
```

Comment: I am clear about the second part. So my understanding about CRON is that it can call a script and schedule the job. I was not sure about what I have to write in the script to call the webservice. I have a wsdl and it has an operation getAllRoles every monday i need to call this webservice. It does not take any parameters. Could you please let me know how I could move ahead in writing the script as I am new to this. Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the link where they show how to query a web service using curl ?  Because what you need to know is all there.

Comment: I have gone through the link and I have a question about it, so that command should be written in a script and saved as .sh file? Also could you let me know why "https://sandbox.mediamind.com/Eyeblaster.MediaMind.API/V2/AuthenticationService.svc" it was used. How is it taking the request.xml?