# How to make Java code that opens the program hourly

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to make code that opens hourly programs made in Java. I have little knowledge of `java`. I tried to do similar below but it doesn't work as I want.

#### Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
          String[] s = new String[] {"C:\\Program Files\\BraveSoftware\\Brave-Browser\\Application\\brave.exe"};
          Process process = runtime.exec(s);        
     }
}
```

Comment: I didn't really understand the question. Did you mean "Running the program at a certain time?"

Comment: Same here, it is really not clear what you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for running this program in a scheduled manner, you can use something like
[Task Scheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10) in windows or [Crontab](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) in case of UNIX systems.

You need not install and run Java for that. But, if you really need it to be executed using a java code, then you can use inbuilt scheduling options in Java. One of the approach is to use a `TimerTask` . Added an example below

```
public class Task extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        
        try {
            // I don't know, what is this app, basically you execute the logic here
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            String[] s = new String[] { "C:\\Program Files\\BraveSoftware\\Brave-Browser\\Application\\brave.exe" };
            Process process = runtime.exec(s);
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Do your thing with the errors!
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

And your scheduler goes like this.

```
public class Scheduler {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create a timer for scheduling
        Timer schduleManager = new Timer(); 
        
        //Create your task instance
        Task taskInstance = new Task(); 
        
        //Scheduler your task repeatedly - every one hour
        schduleManager.schedule(taskInstance, 0, TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1));
        
        System.out.println(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1));
        
        // Keep your code running - an eg.
        while(true);
        
    }

}
```

The program has to be exited forcefully with a `Cntrl+C` or console kill. There are other similar options , using different libraries as well, like

- java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService
- Quartz Scheduler

And more. You can explore on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot then you can use Scheduler annotation

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60 * 60 * 1000
```

Comment: Yeah, a person that states to be an absolute beginner, for sure understands that.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a job requiring Java's ***ScheduledExecutorService***. According to Java's documentation

> The ***ScheduledExecutorService*** interface supplements the methods of its
> parent ExecutorService with schedule, which executes a Runnable or
> Callable task after a specified delay. In addition, the interface
> ***defines scheduleAtFixedRate and scheduleWithFixedDelay, which executes
> specified tasks repeatedly, at defined intervals***.

Here's an example from its Javadoc that sets up a *ScheduledExecutorService* to beep every ten seconds for an hour:

```
 import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
 class BeeperControl {
   private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
     Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

   public void beepForAnHour() {
     final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
       public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); }
     };
     final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle =
       scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
     scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
       public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
     }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
   }
 }
```

Here is a link to a [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20388073/2851311) that uses ScheduledExecutorService to run a task at a specific time.

Another alternative is to run your task as a CRON job. Here's a link to a [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11840093/2851311) that uses CRON to schedule a Java program.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question correctly you can use Thread.sleep() to idle and then start the Process.

So I guess something like this would work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("path\\to\\file.exe");
    while (true) {
        pb.start();
        Thread.sleep(Duration.ofHours(1).toMillis());
    }
}
```

Comment: NOOOOOOOO... this is a TERRIBLE idea.